# What are options for implementing a standard queue type?

Tags: implementation, queue, standard-library

As some examples of standard queue types:

- C++ has [`deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) (`queue` is just a wrapper around it), which is typically implemented as a doubly-linked list of arrays.
- C# has [`Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-7.0), which uses a resizable circular buffer.
- Swift doesn't officially have a queue type, but some standard library algorithms that need one use [`ContiguousArray`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray), as it implements the necessary methods.

What are the advantages and disadvantages to each approach? What approaches are the most common?

Comment: I don't think this is really a language design/implementation question; queues are implemented in many projects, not just compilers/interpreters or standard libraries, and there don't seem to be any specific concerns about implementing a queue for a language's standard library vs. for a third-party library.

Answer (score 2):

The way they teach you in universities and data structure courses is to take a variable-length data structure (the canonical example is a `LinkedList`, but anything like an `ArrayList`, `Vector` or something you can resize will do), extend it into a queue and only provide queue methods, hiding the original container methods. For example:

```
class List {
    method append(data) {...}
    method prepend(data) {...}
    method remove(index) {...} // could be some other form of remove like remove current node if you use a linked list
    // other methods
} 

class Queue extends List {
    // could use something like private inheritance if you're using something like c++
    // otherwise, best practice is to just map original methods of list to error
    method append(data) {error} 
    method prepend(data) {error} 
    method remove(index) {error} 
    method enqueue(data) {super.append(data)}
    method dequeue() {return super.remove(0)} // assuming 0 indexing
    // other queue methods
}
```

How you implement enqueue and dequeue depend on which data structure/ADT you use. Contiguous memory doesn't make much of a difference here as even Linked Lists have O(1) head and tail removal (it's just removing the first/last node)

Comment: This feels like a non-answer. Perhaps my question wasn't clear, but I meant to ask about what underlying data structure to use.

Comment: > take a variable-length data structure

Comment: You asked which data structure to use, I answered that it doesn't matter which one so long as it's resizable. That's the answer. It may not have been what you were expecting but it's an option. @Bbrk24